# redirect to another page by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jquery-1.8.0.min.js on my site and I need make redirect in some situations.

I was try this:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h4>Some text....</h4></div>')
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Dialog title...',
        zIndex: 10000,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                var loc = window.location;
                var currentURL = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname;

                var newUrl = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + 'Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=' + urlencode(currentURL);
                $('<div style="dispaly:none;"></div>').appendTo('<body>').html('<a id="loginredirect" href="' + newUrl + ' "><br /></a>');
                $('#loginredirect').click();
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

but this doesnt work :-(
so i try this:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h4>Some text....</h4></div>')
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Dialog title...',
        zIndex: 10000,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                var loc = window.location;
                var currentURL = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname;

                var newUrl = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + 'Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=' + urlencode(currentURL);
                $(window.location).attr('href', newUrl);
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

but this doesnt work too...

Any idea where is the problem?

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**
If i was trying window.location.hrej = newUrl, FF ErrorConsole show me this:
NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI: Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIDOMLocation.href]
 in localhost/Content/scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js

and browser dont redirect to newUrl in IE, FF and Chrome...

Comment: `location` object is not a DOM element and you cannot convert it to a jQuery object.

Comment: window.location.href = newUrl should do the trick

Comment: can you alert newUrl? my guess is, you need a / after the loc.host

Comment: karthikr: really thanks... I am stupid :-) ... a / was really missing...

Comment: I will just make this an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newURL` is missing a trailing `/` after `loc.host`

```
var newUrl = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + 'Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=' + urlencode(currentURL);
window.location.href = newUrl;
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a jquery for this , just try,

```
window.location.href = new_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, replace this line:

```
$(window.location).attr('href', newUrl);
```

for this one

```
window.location.href = newUrl;
```

that should do what you want.